# confluence lag (Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction)

Tags: exception, innodb, confluence

Hi guys i detected the error of Lock wait time exceeded. I had killed some sleeping processes after using the command (show processlist;). I am new to such things. How should i go forward in dealing with the issue? Much appreciated.

mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name:
Status:
=====================================
170614 19:47:11 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 30 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 4356225 1_second, 4356217 sleeps, 399389 10_second, 477577 background, 477574 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 4381297
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 755480, signal count 713019
Mutex spin waits 245327, rounds 7550453, OS waits 221338
RW-shared spins 522955, rounds 15688190, OS waits 521914
RW-excl spins 2476, rounds 366430, OS waits 11866
Spin rounds per wait: 30.78 mutex, 30.00 RW-shared, 147.99 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 64C202
Purge done for trx's n:o < 64C202 undo n:o < 0
History list length 1543
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 5743968, OS thread handle 0x7f9c43efb700, query id 165261125 localhost root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 64C200, not started
MySQL thread id 5743970, OS thread handle 0x7f9c8c32a700, query id 165261100 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1F7, not started
MySQL thread id 5743964, OS thread handle 0x7f9c43eba700, query id 165261042 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1FD, not started
MySQL thread id 5743966, OS thread handle 0x7f9c43f3c700, query id 165261052 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1E9, not started
MySQL thread id 5743963, OS thread handle 0x7f9c600de700, query id 165260871 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1E8, not started
MySQL thread id 5743955, OS thread handle 0x7f9c62e67700, query id 165260740 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1E6, not started
MySQL thread id 5743956, OS thread handle 0x7f9c60223700, query id 165260746 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1E3, not started
MySQL thread id 5743933, OS thread handle 0x7f9c62f6b700, query id 165260633 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1E1, not started
MySQL thread id 5743938, OS thread handle 0x7f9c631f5700, query id 165260639 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64C1E0, not started
MySQL thread id 5743940, OS thread handle 0x7f9c60327700, query id 165260488 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64B85D, not started
MySQL thread id 5740865, OS thread handle 0x7f9c8c4b0700, query id 165259485 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
---TRANSACTION 64B85C, not started
MySQL thread id 5740864, OS thread handle 0x7f9c62ee9700, query id 165259486 localhost 127.0.0.1 confluence
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
12840 OS file reads, 27451450 OS file writes, 7033960 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 4.87 writes/s, 1.27 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 87 merges
merged operations:
 insert 117, delete mark 5, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 553229, node heap has 747 buffer(s)
49.83 hash searches/s, 15.97 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 19654516867
Log flushed up to   19654516867
Last checkpoint at  19654516867
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
3329939 log i/o's done, 0.63 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 274726912; in additional pool allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 941535
Buffer pool size   16383
Free buffers       1
Database pages     15635
Old database pages 5751
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 24724, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 12721, created 15326, written 23176291
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 4.03 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 15635, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[199]:cur[5], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 1169, id 140309616068352, state: waiting for server activity
Number of rows inserted 2143631, updated 1036354, deleted 1616016, read 1717367473
0.30 inserts/s, 0.17 updates/s, 0.30 deletes/s, 57.86 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
![enter image description here][1]
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

ERROR:
No query specified   (oops - ; after \G)

Comment: anybody there to help?

Comment: I love the details that you provided for your questions however, would be good to know what logs in Confluence. Have you seen any specific error or warning? Is this happening always or you are seeing it occasionally?

Comment: Where did you get "lag"?